# If a TextBox entry is empty, how do I get it to still run the code but leave the space blank?

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox, replaceall, replacewith

Disclaimer: I am not a tech guy, and my chosen profession is law. I know just enough to help my company create forms that can be filled out by using macros in Word.

I have gotten as far as completing the code and have it all working properly. However, I have realized that not all `TextBox`es will be filled out every single time. I want the unused `TextBox` to appear blank in the Word doc instead of having the place holders. Example of the code and issue is below.

```
If TextBox1.Value <> "" Then _
  ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute _
  FindText:="<T Agent>", ReplaceWith:=UCase(TextBox1.Value), Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Currently, if I do not fill out textbox 1, it will leave the place holder as `<T Agent>` on the Word doc. I want it to be just blank.

What do I need to add to make this work?
Does that make sense?

Comment: I see no C# in this question, and don't understand what WinForms has to do with it; please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Try altering the ReplaceWith statement to execute an if statement that checks the state of the TextBox before it is written. Something like:

```
ReplaceWith:=IIf(TextBox1.Value="<T Agent>", "", TextBox1.Value)
```

The double I in IIF is intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the If TextBox1.Value <> ""

```
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="<T Agent>", ReplaceWith:=UCase(TextBox1.Value), Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Do the replace all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you even need to use an IF to find out whether the TextBox contains anything. If it's "empty" it returns a zero-length string, which is exactly what you want to write to your document:

```
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute _
   FindText:="<T Agent>", _
   ReplaceWith:=UCase(TextBox1.Text), Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

(I put in the _ in order to make the long line of code more readable - you can delete them and bring everything together on a single line, if you prefer.)

Note that my preference for coding this would be to assign the textbox's content to a variable and work with that:

```
Dim sTextBox1Value as String
sTextBox1Value = TextBox1.Text
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute _
  FindText:="<T Agent>", ReplaceWith:=UCase(sTextBox1Value), _
  Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```